# Fluxbox borderWith on focused Maximized windows

Tags: fluxbox

Using fluxbox for a few days now trying to get things setup as I want them.

I added window.focus.borderWidth: 2 (and .borderColor: white) to my .fluxbox/overlay so I can easily determine what window is focused without looking down to the toolbar. This works perfect.. except for:

If a window is maximized such as Firefox then no focus border appears, so for maximized windows I cant use the same visuals to determine if they are focused. Why the obsession: I use deco: border (i dont need window title) on a multi-head setup so I like to know whats in focus.

In a nutshell, I want large border for focused maximized windows in Fluxbox, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

submit a feature request to sf.net/projects/fluxbox. what you want is currently blocked by this piece of code in src/WindowState.cc:

```
38 bool WindowState::useBorder() const {
39     return !fullscreen && maximized != MAX_FULL && deco_mask & DECORM_BORDER;
40 }
```

(if maximized is not vertical-only or horizontal-only)